# How to remove substring rightside of a keyword

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to remove text to the right side of a keyword. I have this text:

```
a = "` 27 3 4400 Local/STD secs Hide Hide ` View Detail More List."
```

I want to remove `'Hide'` and all of the text right side of it.

I tried to do this by regex:

```
a.scan(/?:Hide/)
```

It just gives me the occurrence of `'Hide'`.

Comment: `a.sub(/Hide.*/, '')`

Comment: @AvinashRaj, not quite: `"Hideous blah blah Hide".sub(/Hide.*/, '') #=> ""`. Note question refers to "keyword", not "substring". All is well with `sub(/\bHide\b.*/, '')`.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the text after `Hide` till the end of the line by using

```
a.sub(/Hide.*/, '')
```

- `Hide` - literally match `Hide`
- `.*` - as many characters as possible after that

[**Demo**](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/ce12c/2)

Answer (score 3):

`partition` will be easy.

```
a.partition("Hide").first
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a regexp

Use substring methods and [`String#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-index).

```
index = a.index('Hide')      # Get the index of `Hide` and subtract by one
substring = a[0...index]     # Get substring from zero'th index to the index of Hide
```

Example:

```
a = "27 3 4400 Local­/STD secs Hide Hide blah blah blah"­
a[0...a.ind­ex('Hide')­]
#=> "27 3 4400 Local/STD secs "
```

Comment: Using `-1` is not that clever. And when `"Hide"` is at the left edge of the original string, it will give a wrong result (the entire string) instead of the expected empty string.

Comment: Remove that `-1` and use `a[0...index]` or `a[0, index]` instead

Comment: Be aware that `a.index('Hide')` return `nil` if `a` does not contain `'Hide'`

Comment: I suggest you use `index = "Hideous Hide".index /\bHide\b/ #=> 8` (paired with @Stefan's suggestion) since the OP specifies "keyword".

Answer (score 2):

You said you want to remove text identified by a `keyword`, not by a `substring`. For that I suggest you use a regex:

```
r = /
    .*?      # Match any characters any number of times, lazily
    (?=      # Begin a positive lookahead
    \bHide\b # Match 'Hide' preceded and followed by a word break
    )        # end positive lookahead
    /x       # Extended/free-spacing regex definition mode

"Blah, blah Hide Hide blah, blah"[r]
  #=> "Blah, blah "
"Hideous blah, blah Hide Hide blah, blah"[r]
  #=> "Hideous, blah, blah "
```

Notice the need for *lazily*:

```
"Blah, blah Hide Hide blah, blah"[/.*(?=\bHide\b)/]
  #=> "Blah, blah Hide "
```

Edit: a simpler (better) solution would be what @AvinashRaj suggested in a comment on the question, modified as I suggested in another comment.